# What is the Abel sum of this series and why?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, divergent-series

$\sum_{n=0}{a_n}$ is Abel summable to L if $f(x) = \sum_{n=0}{a_nx^n}$ converges on $[0,1)$ and $\lim_{x\rightarrow 1-} f(x) = L$.

I know $\sum_{n=0}{(-1)^nx^n}$ is convergent on that interval but what is its Abel sum?

Help appreciated.

Comment: Also, all of your sigmas are without bounds... it doesn't quite make sense. $\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n$ has a different Abel sum than $\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^n$

Comment: Also, what's preventing you from directly evaluating the series? It happens to be one of the simplest series to come by, and it goes by the name *geometric series*.

Comment: Also, the solution [happens to be on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation_of_Grandi%27s_series#Abel_sum).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that the sum starts when $n=0$, the answer is $\frac{1}{2}$, because$$\lim_{x\to1^-}\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^{n}x^n=\lim_{x\to1^-}\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-x)^n=\lim_{x\to1^-}\frac1{1+x}=\frac12.$$